# Update Inconsistent on DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I've implemented a lambda function. During testing, updating of the item's attribute seems inconsistent. Most of the time it won't update and seldom it will update.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
const Responses = require('../common/API_Responses.js');
const Dynamo = require('../common/Dynamo.js');

const tableName = process.env.collectionTableName;

exports.handler = async event => {
    console.log('event', event);

    if(!event.pathParameters || !event.pathParameters.collection_id) {
        return Responses._400({message: 'Missing parameters'});
    }

    const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const ID = event.pathParameters.collection_id;
    console.log(data);
    let res = {};
    let isKey = false;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        
        if (key == 'collection_name' || key == 'sex' || key == 'designer' || key == 'period') {
            console.log('key', key);
            isKey = true;
            res = Dynamo.edit(ID, tableName, key, data[key]);
        } 
    });

    if (isKey) {
        return Responses._200({message: `ID: ${ID} has been updated.`, res});
    } else {
        return Responses._400({message: `ID: ${ID} has not been updated.`, res});
    }
    
}
```

`Dynamo.js` snippet

```
const Dynamo = {
    async edit (ID, tableName, updateKey, updateValue) {
        let keyName = '';
        
        if (tableName == collectionTableName) {
            keyName = 'Collection_ID';
        } else if (tableName == patternTableName) {
            keyName = 'Pattern_ID';
        } else {
            throw Error('tableName unidentified.');
        }

        const params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Key: {[keyName]: ID},
            UpdateExpression: 'SET #updateKey = :updateValue',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':updateValue' : updateValue
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#updateKey': updateKey,
            },
            ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
        };

        console.log(params);

        let res = '';
        res = await documentClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw Error(err);
            } else {
                return data
            }
        }).promise();

        console.log('res', res);
        return res
    },
}
```

Hoping can somoeone can help me on this. Thanks in advance.

I've searched and tried debugging but hit a wall.

Comment: how is your dynamo table configured? eventual consistency...?

Comment: @DanielA.White I've set everything to default except my billing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with how JavaScript works and its inherent asynchronous nature? In your code you fail to await any of your Async functions, so that forces the lambda to end as it's not waiting for the update to happen.

```
res = await Dynamo.edit(ID, tableName, key, data[key]);
```

Comment: I've implemented `await` on the `Dynamo.edit() function. However, I am still encountering the same problem.

Comment: That was an example of where you missed it, make sure you await for every async call you make.